# How to attach files in MIRO

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have to create report/FM for attachment (a image & a file, both in .TIF format) in `MIRO` Transaction Code.

In my code it is updating in table but not in `MIRO`. Can anybody check my code where I am doing a mistake.

I have to pass Business object , business key.

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b12 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
PARAMETERS: p_file   TYPE localfile,
            p_objid  TYPE swo_typeid,
            p_bo     TYPE swo_objtyp.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1.
DATA:
  li_content   TYPE  STANDARD TABLE OF soli,
  ls_content   TYPE soli,
  li_objhead   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF soli,
  lwa_folmem_k TYPE sofmk,
  lwa_note     TYPE borident,
  lwa_object   TYPE borident,
  lwa_obj_id   TYPE soodk,
  lwa_content  TYPE soli,
  lwa_fol_id   TYPE soodk,
  lwa_obj_data TYPE sood1,
  lv_ep_note   TYPE borident-objkey,
  lv_lifnr     TYPE lifnr,
  lv_file      TYPE string,
  lv_filename  TYPE c LENGTH 100, " file name and ext
  lv_extension TYPE c LENGTH 4. " extension only

REFRESH: li_content[], li_objhead[].

CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_UPLOAD'
  EXPORTING
    filename                      = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\123.TIF'
   filetype                       = 'BIN'
   TABLES
   data_tab                       = lt_data

CALL FUNCTION 'SO_CONVERT_CONTENTS_BIN'
    EXPORTING
      it_contents_bin = li_content[]
    IMPORTING
      et_contents_bin = li_content[].

  CALL FUNCTION 'SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET'
    EXPORTING
      region                = 'B'
    IMPORTING
      folder_id             = lwa_fol_id
    EXCEPTIONS
      communication_failure = 1
      owner_not_exist       = 2
      system_failure        = 3
      x_error               = 4
      OTHERS                = 5.
```

Comment: Miro is SAP-Standard. Inspect the possibility of exits/badi's, where You surely can place Your code, almost as it is now.

Comment: Please also be more precise. Like, wether You to upload an invoice or similar before/during/after miro or if You want to download miro data before/during/after the usage of miro to any computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel, in my view.

If you need just to attach files in MIRO then you can use excellent tool called GOS (Generic Object Services). It has plenty of features including [attaching files to business objects](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6da22ab86c4b10148098e6e14b8ef990/7.01.18/en-US/4d06062f6c3f2102e10000000a42189e.html) (MIRO holds invoices which are business objects too) and much much more.

What you need to do is just to call *Attachment list* item in GOS menu and add target file to attachment list of MIRO object.

[image][image]

All files are treated by system as SAPoffice documents and technically are stored in `SOOD` and `SOFM` tables.
Additionally, if you are not satisfied with native attach functionality you can easily extend GOS menu by [adding your own services](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/EN/b8/a4e7377a98c17fe10000009b38f842/frameset.htm). These services can call your FMs which would save your files wherever you want.